# How do I enable the onboard gfx card alongside a discrete graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics

My motherboard is M3a78-cm and the new card I installed is the GT 520 from NVIDIA. I tried looking around the BIOS settings but I was only able to toggle between having the DisplayPort (internal gfx) on or off. Is this at all possible with my motherboard? Could I download some BIOS update to give me the option to enable both, or is there a way to dig deeper into my computer to make this work? I want to run two monitors, and I know I can do this with the new card alone, but I want to be able to run 3 at some point in the future.

Comment: I believe that you cannot do this, the dedicated card overrides the integrated one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.cizgi.com.tr/resource/vfiles/cizgi/pms_file/80/m3a78cm_en.pdf) for [that motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2Plus/M3A78CM/#download):

> Page x:
>
> Dual VGA output supports: RGB & DVI, DVI & DP, and RGB & DP
>
> Page 1-19:
>
> Due to chipset limitaion, when a DisplayPort monitor is plugged in, PCIe x 16 slot may not be able to support an add-on card. Set the **DisplayPort Configuration** item in teh BIOS to **[Enabled]** before using the DisplayPort.
>
> Page 2-24:
>
> **Primary Display Adapter [GFX-GPP-PCI]**
>   Allows you to select which graphics controller to use as the primary boot device.
>   Configuration options: [GFX-GPP-PCI] [GPP-GFX-PCI] [PCI-GFX-GPP]
>
> **Primary Video Controller [GFX0-GPP-IGFX-PCI]**
>   Configuration options: [GFX0-GPP-IGFX-PCI] [GPP-GFX0-IGFX-PCI] [PCI-GFX0-GPP-IGF] [IGFX-GFX0-GPP-PCI]
>   
>   `IGFX = internal VGA port`
>   `PCI   = PCI     video card`
>   `GPP   = PCIex1  video card`
>   `GFX0  = PCIex16 video card`
>   (`GFX is not defined!`)

Taken together, what it means is that multiple video adapters *are* supported, but may not work depending on the particular configuration that you are using. Specifically, using the DisplayPort *may* prevent you from also using a PCIex16 card (which the [GT 520 is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_500_Series#Products)), so disable the DisplayPort if you are not actually using it.

Check that the *Primary Display ** settings are set to the defaults because they best support what you want. However, you may want to experiment with different settings for *Primary Display **Controller***, particularly the `[IGFX-GFX0-GPP-PCI]` option (you’ll have to redefine the primary in your OS).

Comment: This worked, specifically the PDC setting you recommended! Thanks a lot :D! Now I have 2 monitors with the tv being the 3rd. My only remaining question is, is it possible to make the monitor coming out of the gt520 the primary monitor? There is a setting to fuse monitors 2 & 3 that I want to use so I can actually see what I am playing on my tv instead of having to drag it off both screens to have it visible on the tv.

Comment: Setting the Primary Display Adapter to GFX-GPP-PCI and the Primary Video Controller to GFX0-GPP-IGFX-PCI (both defaults) *should* set the GT50 as the primary. Failing that, you should be able to set it in the Windows Display Properties depending on which version of Windows you are using.